# Git directory pointing to different directory / directory sync/clone

Tags: wordpress, git, synchronization, windows-7-x64

I'm developing a WordPress theme and all WordPress themes must be in this folder in order to work:

```
C:\xampp\wordpress\wp-content\themes\
```

I store my themes in Dropbox (I know of the downsides) and they reside there:

```
D:\Dropbox\Code\
```

Question - is it possible to create some kind of a shortcut/clone/whatever that will automagically update/create/delete files/folders, just in general perfectly sync two directories together?

So when I edit something in `D:\Dropbox\Code\Theme\index.php` the change will happen automatically in `C:\xampp\wordpress\wp-content\themes\Theme\index.php` etc.? I'd love it to work without any 3rd party software and smoothly (would be perfect if stuff like LiveReload for browser would work in this config!).

I've tried with standard Windows shortcut, but unfortunately it doesn't work with WordPress.

Sorry if this not a Git question (might be as well WP or even OS related one).

Comment: Would a symbolic link from C:\xampp\wordpress\wp-content\themes to your Drop box themes folder work for you?

Comment: Wow, never really heard about symbolic links. It seems to be working, but how to handle git? For example is there any difference if I do "cd C:\xampp\theme" (symoblic link) & "D:\dropbox\theme" (original content) and do for example "git add ."?

Comment: Yeah either will work. A symbolic link just points to another location on your computer. It's what shortcuts do. So there is actually only one location containing all the data which is at D:\Dropbox\Code\. No copies of the themes are made, but you will have them backed up with Dropbox.